# How to hide/print Detail band at report with condition based on field's value?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to print my detail band with expression based on field value but seems not working. I've tried:

```
new.java.lang.Boolean($F{Code}.equals("COD"))

new Boolean($F{Code}.equals("COD"))

$F{Code}.equals("COD")

$F{Code}  == "COD"
```

Any idea to make it works?

```
<band height="60">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{Code}.equals("COD")]]></printWhenExpression>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="370" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="dd9cb634-244f-4dd4-b329-4c90e406afba"/>
            <text><![CDATA[One Detail]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
    <band height="56">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="370" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="d4259182-215b-4b3e-9673-bcd6cb5ac355"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Another detail]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
```

Comment: `I want to print my detail band with expression based on field value but seems not working` - Your question is unclear. Are you using printWhen expression for hiding Band, textFields? You should post **small, minimal** example to reproduce the problem

Comment: your question is unclear, when do you like to hide the band?, when the field `Code` equals the string `"COD"`? if so I guess you are close just remove `new.` so it becomes `java.lang.Boolean($F{Code}.equals("COD"))` in later versions there is no need to wrap in Boolean you can just use `$F{Code}.equals("COD")` (all this presuming that `$F{Code}` is of class `java.lang.String`)

Comment: it actually also depend on language your are using in report, my suggestion is presuming you are using "java" if you are using groovy also `$F{Code}  == "COD"` should work, if still not working you need to pass a [mcve] a small jrxml with some sample data that shows your problem

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Basically yes, I wish to hide one detail band when the field  "Code" is COD, and i've check the $F{Code} is java.lang.String class. I tried to use $F{Code}.equals("COD") or $F{Code} == "COD" , however the result is not working.

Comment: I've figured out the problem. to compare the string , use ' instead if "